# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a saga which dispatch a `SIGNIN` action to the store.

```
const { status, userDetails: {token} } = yield take(SIGNIN);
yield put({ type:SIGNIN, payload: {status, token} });
```

Inside the `reducer` I am able to log the `payload` which is it contains the property and value of `status and token`,

```
authenticated: createReducer(userAuthenticated, {
    [SIGNIN](state, action) {
        console.log(action.payload);
    }
})
```

but when I try to access the property inside the `payload object` by doing `console.log(action.payload.status)`, I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`. Are we not suppose to access the property of the payload object inside the reducer?

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(action.payload);` ??

Comment: this is the output for console.log(action.payload) `Object {status: true, token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkI…DE1fQ.KAK_pfh2aajCUW5wtFHc8OogjSSEa4o4vv6XLWSRKYI"}`

Comment: are you running console.log(action.payload.status) in the reducer or somewhere else? Also, its a bit unusual to be 'taking' and 'putting' an action back to back, you generally wouldn't need a Saga to do that but should just handle the formatting in the action generator or prior

Comment: try to write the console.log() in an if condition as it may happen that the reducer is called without the payload. Try  `[SIGNIN](state, action) {
        if(action.payload) {console.log(action.payload.token, action.payload.status);}
    }`